# Composer install using env variables and circleci

Tags: symfony, composer-php, circleci

I've set up circleci with my Symfony2 project, however I am having some issues with my values in parameters.yml.

I don't want to store my production variables in `parameters.yml.dist`, so I've set up the following:

```
"incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "env-map": {
            "database_host": "DATABASE_HOST",
            "database_port": "DATABASE_PORT",
            "database_name": "DATABASE_NAME",
            "database_user": "DATABASE_USER",
            "database_password": "DATABASE_PASSWORD"
        }
}
```

Which automatically replaces the values in `parameters.yml` with my environment variables when I run `composer install`. This works perfectly fine locally.

I've added the env variables to circleci, but when `composer install` is run in circleci it doesn't use the env variables, only the values from `parameters.yml.dist`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post here your `circle.yml` config (just part with environment variables)

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov my env variables are stored in the circleci UI, not in the circle.yml file

Comment: Maybe that's the problem? I think your UI should generate `circle.yml` according to your preferences. But you always can just edit this file yourself and solve the problem.

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov hm, I just tried to add the variables to the config file, but it still doesn't work